# Simple C++ program failing on windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, mingw

I am little new to windows platform and I may be getting something entirely wrong.

I have this simple program in C++ with Qt.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <QWidget>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app = QApplication(argc, argv);
    std::cout << "abc";
   app.exec();
   return 0;
}
```

I was able to succesfully build and link it, however when I try to run it:
Process finished with exit code -1073741515 (0xC0000135)
appears.

I think problem is with the loader so I added C:\Program Files\Qt\6.3.2\mingw_64\lib to the path, did not help.

Any ideas ?
I am using CLion, mingw, cmake, Qt6.

Update:
Using dependency walker, I got the following result:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbUeK.png)

Also, this is quite new computer (may be a problem?).

Comment: Have you tried to launch the compiled executable directly? I'm not familiar with CLion, 0xC0000135 seems to be related to the .Net framework, so it could be an IDE issue (missing .Net framework redistributables?)

Comment: Yeah, I launched it directly, same result. I tried moving it to the directory containing qt libs, did not help.

Comment: @Suthiro  0xC0000135 is unrelated to the .Net framework, it is dll not found error.

Comment: Use this replacement for dependency walker: [https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) the original will have a lot of false positives with a modern compiler.

Comment: I am pretty sure you wanted to add `C:\Program Files\Qt\6.3.2\mingw_64\bin` to the `PATH`, not **\lib**.